# Drupal 7 Form API not returning all values into $form_state

Tags: 7, forms

I have a form with multiple similar fields like so:

```
<?php

example_form($form, &$form_state) {

   for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
       $form[$i]['name'] = array(
           '#title' => t('Name'),
           '#type'  => 'textfield',
       );
   }

   $form['submit_button'] = array(
       '#type' => 'submit',
       '#value' => t('Submit Names'),
   );

   return $form;
}
```

This outputs ten fields and a submit button. However, inside `hook_form_submit` and viewing the values from `dpm($form_state['values'])`, there is only one instance of `name`.

I can easily fix this problem by uniquely naming the field `$form[$i]["name-{$i}"]` but this solution does not seem pragmatic. What is the work around for not individually naming each field uniquely? Why is the not naming the container qualify as unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submitted values are flattened by default. To change that, set the `#tree` property on the container (in this case the form):

```
$form['#tree'] = TRUE;
```